# Site "can't" change username, why?

Tags: webserver, databases, server

There's a website I have an account on, and I needed to change my username. They said they were unable to change that. I requested to just have my account deleted, and then I would create a new account with the same email (As the email I use is paid for privacy and business purposes).

They said that if the account was deleted the old username and the old email could be **not** used again and I honestly just don't understand that. I'm not an expert when it comes to SQL, IIS or similar things but I've never run across that before personally or professionally.

Does anyone have some info on why this might be the case?

Comment: It's impossible for us to say why exactly since we don't know the internals of the systems involved.  But it can be possible, yes - usually because things aren't fully deleted, just marked as deleted, which happens for user support, auditing, compliance, fraud/spam protection, and other reasons.

Comment: Most likely, they are just using a terribly designed system

Comment: Even more likely both: badly designed system justified by fear of not being able anymore to do auditing, fraud/spam protection, being compliant, etc. The whole thing hidden behind the "that's what everybody else does. Shoo!"

Comment: I'm not seeing a security question here at all. This is a database design question.

Answer (score 1):

**Why it may be that way**

As [Xiong Chiamiov](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/16960/xiong-chiamiov) said in their comment, we cannot say *why* the website imposes such restrictions without knowing the internals of the systems involved.

However, many websites do restrict the user ability to change their username. It could be due to a technical reason, such as the username being used as a key in a database (unique identifier), or it could be due to more "usability" related reasons, such as preventing users to switch to a new username if they demonstrated toxic behavior, make auditing/log reviewing easier, or ensure coherence when someone mentions a username. For example, were Xiong Chiamiov to change their username, nobody would be able to directly know what comment I was referring to if I did not repeat its content.

**What can you do?**

I would not go for a GDPR erasure request, simply because keeping username and email addresses is probably a lawful processing, at the very least for auditing purpose and regulatory compliance.

However, I understand that you do not care about your current username, but that you need to reuse your email address. You could then update your profile and change the email to another one*, freeing your email address and making you able to reuse it. While I do not believe changing a username** can fall under [GDPR right to rectification (GDPR Art. 16),](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-16-gdpr/) email address certainly does. (And also for security reasons as one could reset your password. Email ownership is not eternal.)

However, leveraging GDPR would work solely if [you or the company are in the European Union (GDPR Art. 3.)](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-3-gdpr/) They may however not check that and process your request.

*: I would advise you to change your old account email address to one you own and not using some disposable email services. Otherwise, someone else could get ahold of your old account. My best advice would be to use [email sub-addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disposable_email_address#Using_%22sub-addressing%22) reusing your email address like:

```
   johndoe@domain.com
=> johndoe+oldaccount@domain.com
```

**: I'm assuming the username is not the name of the user or any direct identifiers (social security number, passport number, etc.) I do not know what could be enforced if that were the case.